# How do I find $f(x)$ based on this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-functions

So I have this equation:

$$f\left(\frac{x}{3-2x}\right)= x^3-5,$$ and I am supposed to find $f\left(-\frac{2}{7}\right).$ I started by trying to find $f(x)$ based on what was given, but I think I completely confused myself, as I tried to multiply the $x^3-5$ by $3- 2x$ and other stuff like that, and then tried to plug in $f\left(\frac{x}{3-2x}\right)$ back into what I got. Can you please help me at least find $f(x),$ or a simpler way to get $f\left(-\frac{2}{7}\right)?$

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you find an $x$ for which the expression inside the $f$ function equals $-2/7$?

Comment: Several people have pointed out in answers below that you don't actually need to find $f(x)$ in order to find $f(-2/7),$ but the answer from Jaideep Khare points out that there's a fairly quick way to find $f(x). \qquad$

Answer (score 7):

Guide:

Let $$\frac{x}{3-2x}=\frac{-2}7$$

Solve for $x$ by converting it to a linear equation.

Now compute $x^3-5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $$y=\frac{x}{3-2x},$$ then what do you get $f(y)$ in terms of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

- from $\frac{x}{3-2x}=-\frac27 \implies 7x=-6+4x\implies3x=-6$ then find $x$
- evaluate $x^3-5$

the answer should be

> -13

Answer (score 0):

$(f\circ g)(x) = x^3 - 5\\
g(x) = \frac {x}{3-2x}$

We haven't found $f(x)$ yet, but probably don't need to.

We need to find an $x$ such that $g(x) = -\frac {2}{7}$

"By inspection," it just seems kind of obvious that $x = -2$

But if that didn't just jump out at you.

$-\frac {2}7 = \frac {x}{3-2x}\\
4x-6 = 7x\\
3x = -6\\
x = -2$

$(f\circ g)(-2) = -8 - 5 = -13$

Comment: Thank you. I tried 2, not minus 2. I have no idea why I did not try the inverse of 2!